# Maintaining CSS on a pre-built ASP.net website. How can I run this locally on a home linux server?

Tags: apache-2.2, asp.net

I was in charge of the css for a website. I sent in my code to a guy who integrates the css with the dev site. Later they decided it would be better for me to have a more direct role in dealing with the css. I've downloaded everything on the ftp but have no idea how to get this set up. I am running an Apache server on a Fedora Linux install. Is there any way I can set up a local testing server so I can test my changes before ftp'ing them back on the site?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have the ASP.NET source code and also a Windows server because ASP.NET runs  on IIS which is only on Windows. Then you can test the CSS when you want :)